# Secure a PHP GET Parameter coming from salesforce in a email link to the public?

Tags: php, sql, soap, salesforce

I am sending a GET Parameter which is an ID, of course this ID is needed to pull fields from salesforce using the soapclient API.

My issue is because this parameter can easily be changed by a user to a different ID, on load of my page it will pull up other fields based on that other ID the user had altered.

How can I secure this in some form? whether it is from the salesforce end or the php side, My Solutions I came up with are the following but I found tedious.

- Have a field in salesforce that is ticked if user has submitted the data before so old data can not be viewed again when it does a check to see if it was submitted.
- Create a session, grab the get parameter, then redirect to the same page. but that is a bit tedious.

What is the best solution for handling a GET Parameter from a salesforce link that will arrive in a email to the user?

Comment: Depending on what that ID is based on you could hash it and use that as the way to identify other records.

Comment: Hash it in a field in salesforce prior to sending the ID?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you generate these ID's or where you use them. But if you store them somewhere and then retrieve them at a later time you could try and hash them. When the ID gets generated either hash it right away and use this hash as the identifier or, if you only get the ID at a later point (on insertion for example), you could create a hash out of the generated ID and store it in a different field of the same record. Later when you are retrieving or showing records to the user you can hash the ID again and make only requests using the hash. This would be a pretty difficult way for the user to get any other records since they would have to know the hash that was generated for the ID.
Of course it all depends a bit on your implementation. I don't have any personal experience with salesforce, so I don't know what might or might not be preventing you from implementing such an idea.